# Create a folder shortcut in another folder using javascript and Google api v3

Tags: javascript, api, shortcut, drive

I'm trying to create a shortcut of a folder in another folder of my drive using javascript and google api v3, and the code provided by Google is this, but it doesn't work...actually, I don't even understand it. Can someone help me on this?:

```
var fileMetadata = {
  'name': 'Project Plan',
  'mimeType': 'text/plain'
};
drive.files.create({
  'resource': fileMetadata,
  'fields': 'id'
}, function (err, file) {
  if (err) {
    // Handle error
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.log('File Id: ' + file.id);
    shortcutMetadata = {
      'name': 'Shortcut to Project Plan',
      'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.shortcut'
      'shortcutDetails': {
        'targetId': file.id
      }
    };
    drive.files.create({
      'resource': shortcutMetadata,
      'fields': 'id,name,mimeType,shortcutDetails'
    }, function(err, shortcut) {
      if (err) {
        // Handle error
        console.error(err);
      } else {
        console.log('Shortcut Id: ' + shortcut.id +
                    ', Name: ' + shortcut.name +
                    ', target Id: ' + shortcut.shortcutDetails.targetId +
                    ', target MIME type: ' + shortcut.shortcutDetails.targetMimeType);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

EXAMPLE OF ITERATIVE PROCESS FOR CREATING A FOLDER STRUCTURE:

```
  function crearIterativo(original,destino){
          //listo las carpetas que tengo en el original
          gapi.client.drive.files.list({
            'pageSize': 300,
            'q': "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed = false and '"+original+"' in parents ",
            'fields': "nextPageToken, files(id, name, parents)"
          }).then(function(response) {
            var files = response.result.files;
            if (files && files.length > 0) {
              for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) { //Para cada carpeta encontrada, la creo en destino:
                var file = files[i];
                //informo
                appendPre(file.name + ' (' + file.id + ')' + ' ['+file.parents +']');
                arrayFoldOrig[file.name]=file.id;
                //creo carpeta
                var fileMetadata = {
                  'name' : file.name,
                  'mimeType' : 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
                  'parents': [destino]
                };
                gapi.client.drive.files.create({
                  resource: fileMetadata,
                }).then(function(respons) {
                  switch(respons.status){
                    case 200://si va bien, entonces crea estructura
                      var file2 = respons.result;
                      console.log('Created Folder Id: ', file2.id);
                      console.log('Llamo iterativo: ', file2.id);
                      crearIterativo(arrayFoldOrig[file2.name],file2.id);
                      break;
                    default:
                      console.log('Error creating the folder, '+response);
                      break;
                    }
                });
              //
              }
            } else {
              //appendPre('No files found.');
            }
          });
        }
```

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. Can I ask you about the detail of `it doesn't work...actually`? 2. In your script, `drive` of `drive.files.create` can be used for creating the shortcut? Namely, your script for the authorization have already been able to be used? 3. Can I ask you about the language of your script? It is Javascript or Node.js?

Comment: May be I should answer the last question in first place: I'm working with javascript, and the provided code is for Node.js, so I adjusted but it still doesn't work, it doesn't create the shortcut neither logs an error. About the permissons, yes, I'm working fine copying folders and creating new ones. But my main problem is that I don't understand the code, and there's little information about it, so I can't trace the error.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to confirm your question to correctly understanding it. In your question, 1. You want to convert the script of Node.js to Javascript. 2. You have already done the script for authorizing the scopes for using the API with Javascript. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Correct, I added in my post  an example of the way that I'm using the API for duplicating a folder structure using an iterative process. It's much more complicated than creating a shortcut and it works fine!. Summarizing, I need to know how to set up the Metadata correctly for shortcuts...

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed the modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what it means "modification point" Could you please explain me? Thanks for everything

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. In order to confirm the modification points, I had shown "From" and "to" for your script. In this modification, the mimeType is modified and a property of `shortcutDetails` is added. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/shortcuts)

Comment: This code works for me with js client using gapi.client.drive.files, but since it doesn't have a parent, shortcut get created at 'My drive' root. Once I added 'parents' as Tanaike shows, shortcut appears where I was expecting it. 
It's worth to mention that I was having trouble at first because I wrote 'mymeType', instead of 'mimeType', in such case it created an empty file without error, with mimeType = 'application/octet-stream',. 
Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to create the shortcut using Javascript.
- You have already done the authorization process for creating the file using Drive API.
- You want to know about how to create the metadata for creating the shortcut.
- In your script, you want to create the shortcut with `gapi.client.drive.files.create`.

For this, how about this answer?

#### Modified script:

Please modify your script as follows.

From:

```
var fileMetadata = {
  'name' : file.name,
  'mimeType' : 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
  'parents': [destino]
};
```

To:

```
const targetId = "###"; // Please set the target file ID or folder ID.
var fileMetadata = {
  'name': file.name,
  'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.shortcut',  // Modified
  'parents': [destino],
  'shortcutDetails': {'targetId': targetId},  // Added
};
```

- Please use `application/vnd.google-apps.shortcut` as the mimeType.
- Please set the target file ID or folder ID to `targetId`. For example, when you want to create the shortcut of the folder A, please set the folder ID of the folder A to `targetId`.
- In above case, the shortcut is created to the folder with the folder ID of `destino`.

#### References:

- [Files: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)
- [Create a shortcut to a Drive file](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/shortcuts)

Comment: I think that I've already done (click on the ok button next to your answer?) Othercase please tell me. And again, thanks a lot. Sorry for my slow answer, but I had to quit my proyects for a while and I came back as soon as I could. Best luck!!

Comment: @Fernando De Palma Madrid Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, for shared drive, you may provide additional params. It worked for me in the following format:

```
let params = {
    // Shared drive params
    corpora: "drive",
    driveId: sharedDriveId,
    includeItemsFromAllDrives: true,
    supportsAllDrives: true,

    "name": shortcutName,
    "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.shortcut",
    "parents": [idTargetFolder],
    "shortcutDetails": {
        "targetId": srcFileId
    },
    fields: 'id, webViewLink'
};

gapi.client.drive.files.create(params)
    .then(response => {
        if (response.status != 200) {
            console.error(`shortcut returns ${response.status}: ${response.statusText}`);
            return;
        }
        console.log(`Shortcut created: ${response.result.id}, ${response.result.webViewLink}`);
    }, err => {
        console.error(err);
    });
```